# Measure in PBI with CALCULATE and FILTER

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have one report with 3 visual filters (date, country and type) and a table that list the stores and number of operatios with the aplied filters. I added a column with the number of operations that meet a condition, but this measure is very slow.

[image]

Here the measure:

```
Nº operations with conditions = CALCULATE('OPERACIONES'[Nº lines];
FILTER('OPERACIONES';'OPERACIONES'[id_type_sale] = 4 ||
'OPERACIONES'[id_type_sale] = 5 ||
( 'OPERACIONES'[line_sin_origen]=1 
|| 'OPERACIONES'[line_fuera_plazo]=1 
|| 'OPERACIONES'[line_manual]=1)

))
```

I think that it is slow because the FILTER function is filtering all data in the table (this table has billions of records)

How can I improve this measure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating a calculated column which evaluates your condition for each row only once.

```
SatisfiesConditions =
IF (
    'OPERACIONES'[id_type_sale] = 4
        || 'OPERACIONES'[id_type_sale] = 5
        || 'OPERACIONES'[line_sin_origen] = 1
        || 'OPERACIONES'[line_fuera_plazo] = 1
        || 'OPERACIONES'[line_manual] = 1,
    1,
    0
)
```

Then your measure can be simplified to

```
Nº operations with conditions =
CALCULATE (
    'OPERACIONES'[Nº lines];
    'OPERACIONES'[SatisfiesConditions] = 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is a great solution, but I am using direct query to a SSAS-T and I can't add calculated columns in Power BI.
I could add the column in the model SSAS-T, but I am searching other solutions before alter my model.

Comment: @Mathemagician it is possible calculate the measure only for the data filtered by the visual filters?

Comment: Yes, a DirectQuery should already only pull the data needed for the visual.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Nº operations with conditions :=
CALCULATE (
    [Nº lines];
    'OPERACIONES'[id_type_sale] = 4
        || 'OPERACIONES'[id_type_sale] = 5
        || 'OPERACIONES'[line_sin_origen] = 1
        || 'OPERACIONES'[line_fuera_plazo] = 1
        || 'OPERACIONES'[line_manual] = 1
)
```

In a few situations, I've noticed a significant increase in performance by just removing the FILTER function and filtering implicitly.

Another option would be something like this (not tested):

```
Nº operations with conditions :=
CALCULATE (
    [Nº lines],
    KEEPFILTERS (
        FILTER (
            SUMMARIZE (
                'OPERACIONES',
                'OPERACIONES'[id_type_sale],
                'OPERACIONES'[line_sin_origen],
                'OPERACIONES'[line_fuera_plazo],
                'OPERACIONES'[line_manual]
            ),
            'OPERACIONES'[id_type_sale] = 4
                || 'OPERACIONES'[id_type_sale] = 5
                || 'OPERACIONES'[line_sin_origen] = 1
                || 'OPERACIONES'[line_fuera_plazo] = 1
                || 'OPERACIONES'[line_manual] = 1
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first solution is not possible because the conditions affect to different columns. But I am using a solution like your second suggestion and it is working faster. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filter-arguments-in-calculate/

Comment: Its a lot of trial and error, I would suggest getting DAX studio, it is a very useful tool that can help tune your DAX measures. Hope you find your solution!

Comment: It is a great pattern for KEEPFILTERS and multiple criteria filters on columns in different tables.

Comment: Would you be kind to add another yet another pattern for filtering by columns in two different dimension tables. Say we want dim1[color]=red or dim2[size]=big. Possibly with SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (heard it is faster then SUMMERIZE, and handles multiple tables). I would be grateful.